# In Flutter, how to record app drawings on screen as a video?

Tags: flutter, image, screen, record

I'm working on a Flutter drawing app and I want to be able to capture the drawings as a video. I have checked all possible ways of doing so but none of them seems to be working right. I tried to use `toImage` to save each frame periodically but `toImage` takes long time to encode an image as `png` and it crashes the app. Also, you'll need to scale up the image if you want to have a good quality image, which makes the image size very large.

I also tried to record the screen as a video but there is no good, stable Flutter package for recording screen. I looked into `ffmpeg` and `opencv` but I don't think that they can be used to record screens. I appreciate any feedback.